# Iterating over dictionary- JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have here a script were i fetch info from an api.

```
fetch(url,opts)
.then((response) => {
  return response.json();
})
.then((data) => {
  const newdata = data;
  const balances = newdata['data']['ethereum']['address'][0];
  
  const symbol = balances['balances'][0]['currency'];
  const value = balances['balances'][0]['value'];
  const bal = balances;
  console.log(symbol, value);
  //document.getElementById("tokenBalance").innerHTML = symbol.symbol + "," + symbol.address + "," + value;

  console.log(bal);
});
```

console.log(bal) gives this output
https://ibb.co/DRS5vNv

How can i access from balances(bal) :
currency {symbol & address}
and {value}?
and than print it all in a table format like this:
TokenName, Tokenaddress, balance?

Because the size of the array can change, in my case it has 34 elements but it can have 5 10 or 100

```
{balances: Array(34)}
balances: Array(34)
0:
currency: {symbol: "TOAD", address: "0x463e737d8f740395abf44f7aac2d9531d8d539e9"}
value: 0.00084138
__proto__: Object
1: {currency: {…}, value: 0.9}
2: {currency: {…}, value: 0}
3: {currency: {…}, value: 0}
4: {currency: {…}, value: 1395658765.4499083}
5: {currency: {…}, value: 0}
6: {currency: {…}, value: 0.06632153}
7: {currency: {…}, value: 0}
8: {currency: {…}, value: 0}
9: {currency: {…}, value: 0}
10: {currency: {…}, value: 391.66319725}
11: {currency: {…}, value: 22989070.87819258}
12: {currency: {…}, value: 207933.87278968}
13: {currency: {…}, value: 1}
14: {currency: {…}, value: 0}
15: {currency: {…}, value: 0}
16: {currency: {…}, value: 19304224871.809647}
17: {currency: {…}, value: 1360077933.9251838}
18: {currency: {…}, value: 100}
19: {currency: {…}, value: 1.1219391}
20: {currency: {…}, value: 3e-8}
21: {currency: {…}, value: 0}
22: {currency: {…}, value: 2461419000}
23: {currency: {…}, value: 0}
24: {currency: {…}, value: 529155969901.41156}
25: {currency: {…}, value: 0.10935729}
26: {currency: {…}, value: 4285038710.5060315}
27: {currency: {…}, value: 0}
28: {currency: {…}, value: 0}
29: {currency: {…}, value: 10}
30: {currency: {…}, value: 205.5986161}
31: {currency: {…}, value: 10}
32: {currency: {…}, value: 0.1637196}
33: {currency: {…}, value: 13367128.75739117}
length: 34
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting back a [JavaScript Array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp). Iterate it using [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) or a simple for [for loop](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp).

In your case, something like:

```js
bal.forEach(function(item, index, array) {
  console.log(item.currency, item.value);
});
```

should do the trick.

Comment: unfortunatly it doesnt, i get a Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: bal.forEach is not a function

Comment: and i want to access all the elements, from currency, symbol nad address and value.

Comment: Without an exact JSON it's hard to give you more specific answers.

Comment: currency holds, symbol and address- so the main categories are currency and value. But i need from currency symbol and address, like currency,.address & currency.symbol & value

Comment: look at the image

Comment: You could always go for `for(k in bal) { console.log(bal[k].currency, bal[k].value); }` -- other than that, without the JSON I don't have a lot of other suggestions.

Comment: please add JSON output as text, I can't follow an random URL from where I am. See also this meta post :  [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: look at the image

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use a for loop

```
for (let i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    console.info(
        data[i].currency.symbol, 
        data[i].currency.address, 
        data[i].value
    );
}
```

Comment: its not working, i tried with data as ism and with bal instead of data, niet

Comment: is `return response.json();` returning `data` as json ?! if so, run it through `JSON.parse`

Comment: can you run `typeof data` and see what type of variable you're getting ? if iterating through `data` doesn't work than apparently it is not an array

Comment: i get back undefined, but look at teh question, i updated it again